# Problem validating XML file against schema file ( XSD file )

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

There is a task assigned to me to validate an XML message against already build XSD file 
When I try to use the "javax.xml.validation.Validator" to validate the xml against it I got the following error which indicates to error at the schema

> SCHEMA : src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name
>   'sau:abstractPayloadType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

here is the schema file named "GIMREQ.xsd"

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cm="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" xmlns:sau="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau"  targetNamespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" schemaLocation="../Common/common.xsd"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="agencyIdType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="agencyNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="msgType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="docType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="docNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\c{1,3}\d{1,14}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="transportType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="localPortCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="localPort">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sau:localPortCodeType">
                <xsd:attribute name="value" use="required">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="sau:transportType"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="reqAgencyInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="custRegPortCode" type="sau:localPort"/>
            <xsd:element name="agencyId" type="sau:agencyIdType"/>
            <xsd:element name="agencyName" type="sau:agencyNameType"/>
            <xsd:element name="requestDate" type="xsd:date"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="reqBusinessInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="reqDocRefNo" type="cm:docRefNoType"/>
            <xsd:element name="reqAccID" type="cm:acctIdType"/>
            <xsd:element name="reqMSGType" type="sau:msgType"/>
            <xsd:element name="reqDocType" type="sau:docType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="reqGeneralInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="reqDocNo" type="sau:docNoType"/>
            <xsd:element name="reqMSG" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="gimReqInfoType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sau:abstractPayloadType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="reqAgencyInfo" type="sau:reqAgencyInfoType" maxOccurs="999"/>
                    <xsd:element name="reqBusinessInfo" type="sau:reqBusinessInfoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999"/>
                    <xsd:element name="reqGeneralInfo" type="sau:reqGeneralInfoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- SaudiEdi Framework -->
    <xsd:complexType name="saudiediGimReqType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="sau:saudiEDIType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="record" type="sau:recordType" maxOccurs="999"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="docType" use="required" fixed="GIM"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="sau:msgIDType" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="msgType" use="required" fixed="GIMREQ"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="saudiEDI" type="sau:saudiediGimReqType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

and here are the imported schema file that is named "common.xsd"

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" xmlns:cm="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sau="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" schemaLocation="saudiedi.xsd"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="transportType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="0"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="5"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="foreignPortCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="localPortCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:positiveInteger">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- Updated by mantesh for CR# 21527 -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="harmonizedCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="16"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="foreignPort">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="cm:foreignPortCodeType">
                <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="cm:transportType"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="localPort">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="cm:localPortCodeType">
                <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="cm:transportType"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="docRefNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="14"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="acctIdType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="percentageType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:positiveInteger">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="emptyPayloadType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="sau:abstractPayloadType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="empty" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="seaMafNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="seaBLSeqNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999.999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="seaBLNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="25"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="seaMafImportType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
            <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="seaMafType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="5"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ownerArbNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerSeqNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="itemSeqNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="agentNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="countryCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="repNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:complexType name="repInfoType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="repNo" type="cm:repNoType"/>
            <xsd:element name="localRepRegistrationPort" type="cm:localPort"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="reqMsgIdType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="17"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="portContractorCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="dischargeAreaType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="importerNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="dONoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="trfMafNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:group name="dOReferenceGroup">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="localRegPort" type="cm:localPort"/>
            <xsd:element name="shippingAgentNo" type="cm:agentNoType"/>
            <xsd:element name="dONo" type="cm:dONoType"/>
            <xsd:element name="dODate" type="xsd:date"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:group>
    <!-- Record reference key -->
    <!-- minOccurs added by Vittal Sakaray -->
    <xsd:complexType name="dOAmeReferenceType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="acctId" type="cm:acctIdType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="docRefNo" type="cm:docRefNoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:group ref="cm:dOReferenceGroup"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="dOSubReferenceType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="acctId" type="cm:acctIdType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="docRefNo" type="cm:docRefNoType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:group ref="cm:dOReferenceGroup"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <!-- Added for release 1.1 -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="frgMafNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="grossWeightType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999.9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ownerEngNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="60"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="packageCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="totalNoOfContainersType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="25"/>
            <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]{4}\s\d{4,20}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerTypeCode">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- Added by Mantesh for PA/PC CR-->
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerHeightType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerLengthType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="temperatureType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="temperatureUOMType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="marksAndNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="tonnageType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999.999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="dischargeStatusType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="buyerNameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="consigneeAdrsType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="175"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="packageType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="stcNumberType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="stcUOMType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="tarifType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="imgdCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ArbMarksAndNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="60"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="portINTLCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="portINTLType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="5"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="6"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- EOD by Mantesh for PA/PC CR -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="totalWeightType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999999999999.9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="generalDescType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="noOfPackagesType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999.9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- Removed the Enumeration type to Integer type [25-Jan-2016] -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="customsGoodsType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="dangerousCodeType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="1|2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="goodsArbDescType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="itemMarksAndChassisNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="22"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="tareWeightType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999.9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="vehicleTransactionRefNoType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- Added for release 1.11 -->
    <!-- Added for release 1.12 Increase the foreign manifest type from 1 to 2 digits -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="frgMafType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="frgMafWeight">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.01"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999.99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- export Data Type declaration starts -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="seaMafExportType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
            <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- export Data Type declaration ends -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="identicalCertificateISNType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- Added by DO request CR Nagoor -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="deofees">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.01"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999.99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- EOA By DO request CR Nagoor -->
    <!-- Added by DEC Clearance CR Nagoor -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="DeptType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="itemMark">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- EOA by DEC Clearance CR Nagoor -->
    <!-- Added for Export and Statistical Shipment Information -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="itemMarkEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="22"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="totalWeightEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999999.999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="totalQuantityEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999999.9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="shipmentTypeEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="containerTypeCodeEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="99"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="goodsWeightEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="999999999999999.999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="goodsQuantityEDECSDC">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0001"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="9999999999999999.9999"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <!-- EOA for Export and Statistical Shipment Information -->
</xsd:schema>
```

and here are the imported schema named "saudiedi.xsd"

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sau="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/sau" xmlns:cm="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.saudiedi.com/schema/common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="abstractPayloadType" abstract="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>abstract payload for domain teams to define</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="msgIDType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\c{1,3}\d{1,14}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="recordType">
        <xs:sequence>       
            <xs:element name="payload" type="sau:abstractPayloadType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="saudiEDIType" abstract="true" block="extension">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>boilerplate for saudiedi documents</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="record" type="sau:recordType" maxOccurs="999"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="docType" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="sau:msgIDType" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="msgType" use="optional"/>       
    </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract type 'sau:abstractPayloadType' is defined in saudiedi.xsd. But saudiedi.xsd is not `imported` or `included` in the main xsd so it cannot be resolved.

The main xsd imports common.xsd, and common.xsd imports saudiedi.xsd. That does not make the definitions in saudiedi.xsd available to the main xsd.

Your options are:

- `include` saudiedi.xsd in the main xsd. You cannot `import` it because it has the same target namespace as the main xsd.
- change the target namespace of saudiedi.xsd and `import` it into the main xsd (and fix up the references to refer to the new namespace)

Comment: Thanks so much that was the problem BUT another problem showed off after including "saudiedi.xsd" in the the "GIMREQ.xsd" which says **ERROR : cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'req:saudiEDI'**

Comment: That error must be in an xsd that I have not seen. There are no _references_ to element 'saudiEDI' in any of the xsds that you posted.